# CheckBox state not updated when popping fragment off backstack

Tags: android, checkbox, fragment

My main activity has a single content view for my fragments. I have two fragments, both share a single checkbox that can be checked/unchecked in either fragment. The problem I am experiencing is when I have replaced Fragment1 with the Fragment2 and uncheck the checkbox, then press back to pop Fragment2 and resume Fragment1, the checkbox doesn't become unchecked. However, if the checkbox is unchecked in Fragment1 and I check it in Fragment2, pop the backstack, it is checked when Fragment1 is resumed. Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by share a single checkbox? Where are you defining your checkbox?

Comment: @joao2fast4u - The checkbox does the same thing on both fragments, it controls the same data. The checkbox is defined in each fragment.

Comment: Right, could you please show the code where you are checking/unchecking the box and checking its state?